# Problem with running unity webgl app in uwp webview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, unity-webgl

I am trying to load a unity webgl app on my uwp app inside a webview. But it only works when apache server is running on my computer. This is a problem only arising with unity webgl apps and not other webgl apps.

I tried running different webgl apps which run fine without and apache server. So I'm guessing this is a problem with Unity only.

Has anyone else tried running unity webgl app inside a uwp webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out putting the webgl project in

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Packages{packagename}\LocalState

solves the problem and no apache server is needed anymore!